# Using a custom delimiter on Bluetooth receive for Android App Inventor 2

Tags: android, bluetooth, app-inventor

I have searched everywhere but for some reason none of the examples I have found are trying to do this...

Is it possible to have a custom delimiter for when I receive text over bluetooth?

For instance, I will send a string like this to the App:

**"#123:456:789\n"**

- When the app receives # it should start buffering the bytes
- 123:456:789 is the actual data it should save
- and \n is the delimiter at which it should stop

Is this possible using the App Inventor 2?

Thanks!

Comment: see the answer of *sghughes* in your [App Inventor forum thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/O9fgYaoUAlk/8eVxGSK-IsUJ)

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about all inventor 2 but surely it is possible to receive text in the mentioned format in the regular android application which implements Bluetooth spp connection.

Comment: This App is not mine, I have written my own App using Android Studio and yes it is easily possible to achive what he wants to do. But on the above example he wants to use App Inventor...